# Showing a function is negative

Tags: inequality

I have the following function $f:[0,\frac{1}{2}] \to \mathbb{R}$:

$$f(p) = p^2(\log(p))^2 - (1-p)^2(\log(1-p))^2 + (1-2p)\log(p)\log(1-p) + (1-2p)\{p\log(p)+(1-p)\log(1-p)\}$$

The inequality I need to show is $$f(p) \leq 0$$I can show that $f(0) = f(1/2) = 0$, and that $f'(0) = -1$, $f'(1/2) = 0$. The graph of $f$ looks like

[image: valid xhtml].

Since its not monotonic/convex/concave I'm stuck. Any leads are welcome!

Comment: The domain of $f$ doesn't include $0$ because of the  $\log(p)$ terms. How did you get $f(0)=0$?

Comment: In the limit as p goes to 0..  I should have been more clear though.

Comment: Can you prove that $f'$ has only one zero?

Comment: @lhf: I tried that, but the derivative did not look manageable enough.

Comment: Using laws of logs, you can simplify the equation.  You might be then able to take the derivative, as @lhf suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this eventually in a not so elegant way, for the proof outline and more details about where this inequality came from please refer the mathoverflow link https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93271/proving-a-messy-inequality